# Is there a way to click an area in an image map using Selenium's webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I'm new to Selenium and I'm trying to click areas of an image map.

My image map has two areas. The first area triggers JS; the second area acts as a regular link.

I've tried the following:

- Clicking on the image which fails because it's blocked by the area (i.e. 'area element would receive the click')

  ```
  driver.find_element(:css, '.foo img').click
  ```
- Clicking on the area which fails for the same reason (i.e. 'html element would receive the click')

  ```
  driver.find_element(:css, '.foo area').click
  ```
- Moving the mouse (to both areas) and performing a click, which executes a click, but doesn't appear to trigger the image map. It fails on any line after the click.

  ```
  driver.action.move_to(driver.find_element(:css, '.foo img'), 10, 10).click
  ```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Sidenote... I haven't tried using jQuery to trigger the clicks yet. I was hoping to find a pure Selenium solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an issue with Selenium webdriver.  There appears to be a known bug with clicking on area elements.

From their forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-developer-activity/dTSvAm9ysVk

Comment: Official bug report (filed in 2011...) here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2354