# Scraping with RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to webscrape javascript with RSelenium, but I can't get all the way through. Using css selector I was able to click the first bottom, but when I get to second step, where I have to select a state on the map, I get the following error:

"Erro:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException"

```
library(RSelenium)
url<-"http://www.cnj.jus.br/corregedoria/justica_aberta/?"
startServer()
mb <- remoteDriver(browserName="chrome")
mb$open()
mb$navigate(url)
mb$findElement(using="css selector","fieldset:nth-child(5) a:nth-child(4) strong")
mb$findElement(using="css selector","fieldset:nth-child(5) a:nth-child(4) strong")
s<-mb$findElement(using="css selector","fieldset:nth-child(5) a:nth-child(4) strong")
s$clickElement() # Until here everything is fine.
#this part below doesn't work:
d<-mb$findElement("css selector", 'area:nth-child(4)')
d$clickElement() # here a I get the error mentioned above.
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Unfortunately clicking on an imagemap is [problematic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804926/is-there-a-way-to-click-an-area-in-an-image-map-using-seleniums-webdriver) but you could scrape the map/area HTML tags and try to execute the javascript from it (use the web inspector to see what I'm talking about).

Comment: Your suggestion worked well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me with chrome version 52.0.2743.116 and chromeDriver 2.23.409699 and Win 10. You can try as an alternative using a different selector for example:

```
d <- mb$findElement("xpath", "//map/area[4]")
d$clickElement()
```

Also as @hrbrmstr suggested you can execute the javascript directly:

```
mb$executeScript("pesquisaUf('SP');return '';")
```

Comment: dharrison, I was able to get to the tables and download them, but I only download the lines in the first page of the table. If the table has more than 100 lines (registros), I can't download them at once, because it only shows maximum 100 lines. Can you help me with that?